# To find the integer occurence only in a string which contains both alphabets and integer

Tags: java-8

```
Input String s = "123xyz123xyz456xyz456"
expected output= 123-2, 456-2
example input2 s1="abc789azy7891yux7891abc789"
expected output = 789-2, 7891-2
```

If it is by Java hashmap means it might be easy I think so.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better you have some try or at least display what did you do.

compile string with `\\D+` pattern and split it and then use `groupingBy` collector.

```
Map<String,Long> result = 
       Pattern.compile("\\D+") //Compiles the given regular expression into a pattern.
       // Creates a stream from the given input 
       // sequence around matches of this  * pattern.
      .splitAsStream(s) 
      // grouping by split string and count each string(number) occurrence 
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

> {123=2, 456=2}

Comment: If you give me a step by step procedure means it might be helpful for me as I'm completely new to JAVA.